# Unable to parse JSON with Retrofit and GSON - Stack overflow

Tags: java, json, retrofit

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get Retrofit to parse my JSON, I can't wrap my head around. Whenever I run my Retrofit code I get a crash:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$WildcardTypeImpl.<init>($Gson$Types.java:537)
```

and then later on:

```
E/JavaBinder﹕ !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
  {
  "199" : {
  "anncontent" : "content",
  "anndisplaydate" : "Tuesday February 11",
  "announcements_id" : "199",
  "anntitle" : "Newsletter Issue 17"
},
"264" : {
  "anncontent" : "content",
  "anndate" : "2014-10-03 22:37:32",
  "anndisplaydate" : "Friday October 03",
  "announcements_id" : "264",
  "anntitle" : "Timetable"
},
"267" : {
  "anncontent" : "content",
  "anndate" : "2014-10-10 02:41:32",
  "anndisplaydate" : "Friday October 10",
  "announcements_id" : "267",
  "anntitle" : "Author talk with Hugh O’Brien"
}
}
```

My announcement class fields look like this:

```
private String anntitle;
private String anncontent;
private String anndisplaydate;
private Date anndate;
private String announcements_id;
```

My interface looks like this:

```
public interface AnnouncementsAPI {
@GET("/announcements.json")
ArrayList<Announcement> listAnnouncements();}
```

And finally, my Retrofit code looks like this:

```
  RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://MYURL")
            .build();
    AnnouncementsAPI announcementsAPI = restAdapter.create(AnnouncementsAPI.class);
    ArrayList<Announcement> announcements = announcementsAPI.listAnnouncements();

    Log.d("RETROFIT", "Announcemnts: " + announcements.toString());
```

I'm just trying to get an ArrayList of Announcement objects, and I'm not sure how to go about it. Sorry if this has been asked before, but all the previous questions/examples I found used JSON that seemed drastically different to mine.

If anyone has any ideas it'd be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It looks like I'm having a very similar problem. Did you ever figure out what was going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If all object extends same base object, then StackOverflowError: stack size 1036KB exception occurs.

example:

`class BaseBean`

`class A extends BaseBean`
(`class A` contains reference of `class A` and `class B`)
`class B extends BaseBean`
`class C extends BaseBean`

**Implementing above case, there are big possibility for occurring same exception. (don't extend with BaseBean).**

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `retrofit callback` for your interface, like this :

**The interface**

```
public interface AnnouncementsAPI {
    @GET("/announcements.json")
    void listAnnouncements(Callback<ListAnnouncement> callback);
}
```

If you want the return to be a List, Encapsulate the announcement class into another class like so :

**ListAnnouncement.Java**

```
public class ListAnnouncement {
    private List<Announcement> fieldname; //match the fieldname with the field name on the JSON

    //add getter-setter as needed
}
```

**The Retrofit Code**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint("https://MYURL")
            .build();
AnnouncementsAPI announcementsAPI = restAdapter.create(AnnouncementsAPI.class);

final ListAnnouncement listAnnouncement; 
announcementsAPI.listAnnouncements(new Callback<ListAnnouncement>() {
        @Override
        public void success(ListAnnouncement data, Response response) {
            listAnnouncement = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    }
);
```

After that, you can use the `fieldname` on the `ListAnnouncement` `Class` to get the list of `Announcement`.

**Important**

The code above will work if your JSON is indeed a `JSON Array`, by the looks of it, you are getting returns of several `Announcement` objects with different key, which is not a `JSON Array`

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Response should be in this format `HashMap<String,Announcement>`